# Installing Samsung Galaxy S3 driver to connect to eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

I am trying to learn how to use android SDK, and want to run my app on my phone directly from eclipse.

This is what ive done so far:

1) http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

2) Installed drivers via official Samsung website, resulting in slowing down of the boot-time which resulted in re-installing windows.

3) Downloaded Kies which just gets stuck on "Connecting..."

I am hoping that someone could tell me how to do this correctly step-by-step, or let me know if there is a website of some sort that explains how to do this...

Also, is this easier on Nexus?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to unistall all drivers that you got and follow this steps:

1. Download Kies
2. Open Kies
3. Connect your phone and windows will find all drivers that you need.

After that you can uninstall kies if you want and the drivers will stay installed

Comment: As stated above, I did try that.  I should also mention that I did that after re-installing windows.